# Reflection for replace static final String

Tags: java, android, reflection

I am using reflection exactly according to:

[Reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301635/change-private-static-final-field-using-java-reflection)

But everytime I get this error and I don't know why.

```
12-02 17:53:58.650: W/System.err(10646): java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: modifiers
12-02 17:53:58.650: W/System.err(10646):    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:631)
12-02 17:53:58.650: W/System.err(10646):    at com.example.ref.MainActivity.setFinalStatic(MainActivity.java:56)
12-02 17:53:58.650: W/System.err(10646):    at com.example.ref.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
12-02 17:53:58.650: W/System.err(10646):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
12-02 17:53:58.650: W/System.err(10646):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
12-02 17:53:58.650: W/System.err(10646):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
12-02 17:53:58.650: W/System.err(10646):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
12-02 17:53:58.650: W/System.err(10646):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
```

My code below:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Log.i("aaa", "Before = " + securedField);
    try {
        Field stringField = MainActivity.class.getDeclaredField("securedField");
        stringField.setAccessible(true);
        setFinalStatic(stringField, new String("Screwed Data!"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.i("aaa", "After = " + securedField);
}

private void setFinalStatic(Field field, Object newValue) throws Exception {
    field.setAccessible(true);
    Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
    modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
    modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
    field.set(null, newValue);
}
```

Does somebody know where the problem is? Thanks!

Comment: `NoSuchFieldException: modifiers` s modifiers valid field name?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? To change a final field on Field.class?

Comment: Are you sure that the `Field` class actually has that field on it? It *is* `private`, after all, and it's possible that the implementation you're running it on (Android?) doesn't implement `getModifiers()` with a backing field.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: I have the same issue. 
If I run code in IDE, it works normally, 
but if I run mvn clean install, the same issue occurred

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the source code of the android version of [java.lang.reflect.Field](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/d9aed1632ec6fdade72524261cb0489652b25ab4/libart/src/main/java/java/lang/reflect/Field.java).

It does not have a private field `modifiers`. Instead it looks like this

```
public int getModifiers() {
    return accessFlags & 0xffff;  // mask out bits not used by Java
}
```

You tried to adapt an implementation detail of the "normal" jvm to the android jvm. Since it is an implementation detail of another jvm it will not work with android.

But what you try to do will not work anyway. Keep in mind that the compiler inlines constants.

**This will not work**

```
class Greeting {

    public static final String SALUTATION = "Hello";

    public void greet(String name) {
        System.out.println(SALUTATION + " " + name);
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Greeting greeting = new Greeting();
        greeting.greet("John");

        Field declaredField = Greeting.class.getDeclaredField("SALUTATION");
        setFinalStatic(declaredField, "Hey");

        greeting.greet("John");
    }

    private static void setFinalStatic(Field field, Object newValue)
            throws Exception {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
        modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
        modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
        field.set(null, newValue);
    }

}
```

The output will be

```
Hello John
Hello John
```

Also take a look at [JLS, 13.4.9. final Fields and Constants](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.4.9) for details.